Can the Sleeping beauty problem be “solved” by denying its premise of a degree of belief?
From the wiki,

Some researchers are going to put you to sleep. During the two days that your sleep will last, they will briefly wake you up either once or twice, depending on the toss of a fair coin (Heads: once; Tails: twice). After each waking, they will put you back to sleep with a drug that makes you forget that waking. When you are first awakened, to what degree ought you believe that the outcome of the coin toss is Heads?

But why think that a person should have a degree of belief or whether it even makes sense to represent belief in degrees in the first place? If one denies the very premise (and I see no reason for one to accept it in the first place), then it seems that the problem goes away, since there would be no correct degree of belief in the first place.

Do you have a similar criticism fourth-grade math problems involving trains because the train schedules seem unrealistic?

@DavidGudeman bad analogy because the concept of a degree of belief is debated in philosophy

No. The problem can be rephrased as about making a betting decision. It is essentially a problem about ambiguity in setting up decision problems and decision making criteria, degrees of belief as such are moot.

@Conifold that doesn’t evade the problem. If one refuses to accept there’s a correct answer to how much of a degree of belief you should have, there is no correct answer to how much you should bet on it being heads.

Betting can be rephrased in terms of measuring frequencies. Groisman gave a reformulation of the Sleeping Beauty that does not involve humans or betting at all, only placing colored balls into a box and counting them.

@Conifold well I’d have to read about that before offering my opinion on it, although since this sleeping test is only happening once, there are no repeated trials, and thus no frequencies

@Syed - The wikipedia entry about the problem also summarizes Groisman's analysis (and provides a link to his paper). Frequencies here do not refer to repeated trials.

@mudskipper But the wiki contradicts what you just said. “We repeat this procedure a large number of times until the box is full of balls of both colours. A single ball is then drawn from the box.”

It's not necessary to apply a frequentist definition of probability. Any other acceptable definition will lead to the same outcome here.

@Conifold Somewhat frustratingly, Groisman decides to stop short of applying his 'mechanical' approach to the actual problem, but instead only uses it retrospectively for a large number of experiments.
And concerning the betting approach, people seem to confuse the simple bet that is given with the actual "betting game" that SB is offered quite a lot..

Upon any awakening it's 50:50.

In this case the relevant theory isn't statistics or probability theory, it is decision theory - a branch focused on how to make the "best" decision under  different notions of "best". We can give "credence" meaning within a decision theoretic framework.
In decision theory, you can show that depending on how you model the consequences of a wrong/right decision, you will make different decisions -- therefore, best decisions do not always equate to "most predictive".
Case in point - let's make the sleeping beauty problem a bit more ... interesting ;-)

Each time she awakens, we ask her if she thinks it more likely that
head or tails was tossed:
If the coin landed Heads, and she guesses Heads, she is put back to sleep to be awakened on Wednesday (the usual outcome) 
If the coin landed Heads and she guesses Tails she is put back to sleep and awakened again on Tuesday (i.e., they treat her like it was
Tails that was tossed) 
If the coin landed Tails and she guesses Tails she is put back to sleep and awakened again on Tuesday (same as original problem) 
If the coin landed Tails and she guesses Heads she is put to sleep and never reawakened.

If she is awake on Wednesday they ask her again to maintain "single blind" study but the outcome is the same -- she gets to stay away and go home to Prince Phillip.
What should Sleeping Beauty decide to say when the researchers ask her to respond?

If she is indifferent to sleeping, then it doesn't matter, unless she
gets some utility from being "right" in which case she'll spend time
calculating the odds (maybe write a computer simulation to check).
If (like most people) she very much doesn't want this week to be the last
week she is conscious, then she will decide to always guess Tails (even
if we are told that the coin is extremely biased to Heads).

In the original one, it happens to be that she is like the first example because she is trying to be accurate, not "prudent"  (since all outcomes are the same). That corresponds to having a reward of 1 for being right, and 0 for being wrong.

Logic of degrees of truth
Degrees of belief is an important principle in epistemology an logic as well and we'd all be poorer for it if we limited ourselves to "I am convinced of X" or "I am convinced of not X". You loose so much nuance when you pretend that everyone's credence is apportioned like that.
Of course, "the fact of the matter" is that either Heads or Tails was tossed, but you will never know which one.
A well-worn strategy for uncertain scenarios is to made a decision that is correct for the most "future you's" (so kind of like a modal argument -- we want to be correct in the most possible worlds that are reachable from the current world).
In this case our "reward" is simply 1 if we are right and 0 if we are wrong.
For this problem, I tend to agree with David Lewis that you should stick with 50%. The situation is set up so that you get no additional information when you are awakened. Therefore, there is no basis for deviating from the 50% initial probability.
Lets now use the average absolute miscalibration (AAM) as our measure of the cost of being wrong:

Average Absolute Miscalibration = E[(X-p)2]

Where E is the average or expected value, X is the coin's outcome and "p" is the assigned credence. We can see that if we want to minimum AAM, we should pick p=0.5 (50%)

E[X2 - 2pX + p2] = 0.5 - 2p(0.5) + p2 = p2 - p + 0.5

The derivative of this with respect to p is:

2p - 1

The second derivative is:

2

In this case, that means if we find where the derivative (i.e., slope) is 0 we will be at a minimum.
In this case, we get p=0.5 as David Lewis suggested.

What if we condition on the event A := "I have been awakened after the experiment started"?
Given this, we have the following sample space of "awakenings" (Toss Outcome, Day of Week):

{(H,M), (T,M), (T,T), (H,W), (T,W)}

If all that I know is A, does this modicum of information help?

P(H|A) = P(H ∩ A) / P(A) = P(H ∩ A) = P(H)P(A|H) = P(H)

By law of total probability, we surmise P(T|A) = 0.5 as well.
Since P(A) = 1, it isn't a helpful piece of information.
But wait! There are three chances for us to find ourselves awake when Tails is tossed and only two chances when Heads is tossed, and it is equally likely a priori to be heads or tails. Since we can't know which, shouldn't principle of indifference tell us that we should have credence 2/5 or 40% for it being heads?
What happened?
The issue is that we are treating each awakening as independent when in fact they are not.
This means that the naïve sample space I gave was wrong. The true sample space of awakenings are:

{(H,M,W), (T,M,T,W)}

However, our intuition would have us thinking the former since "any awakening is as good as any other".
I  hope this showed how credence can have meaning and be a useful thing even when we are not actually relying on actual repetitions.

The SB problem can be reformulated in terms of probability as

What is the probability that a rational person, in the position of SB, should assign to the event that the coin came up heads?

The phrase "degree of credence" can be explained as "level of confidence", "subjective degree of certainty", and this can in various ways be mapped to a numerical value. In the debate about the SB problem nobody contends this (as far as I know). The standard way of operationalizing "credence", "confidence" or "certainty" is in terms of subjective probability, and there are no problems with that -- the concept is used in various empirical sciences, economy, game-theory, decision theory, and in various technologies, for instance in language modelling in the form of confidence models.
The OP however contends that "credence" might be nonsense and that therefore the problem becomes unsolvable or also nonsense. I believe this is arguably false. If we decide that we don't want to allow "credences" or "probabilities" in the problem statement, the problem doesn't
"softly and suddenly vanished away" like the gleeful Baker in The Hunting of the Snark.
If we don't want to ask SB about her "credence" and don't want to assume that SB understands much (or anything) of probability theory, we can still set up the experiment but tweak the representation and question a bit. The tweaks will not change the essential nature of the experiment, as I hope will become clear; they will merely avoid asking SB to translate any vague feelings of confidence (or lack of confidence) or opinions of being more (or less) certain into precise numerical probability measures:

We ask SB to just make a guess, whether the coin came up heads (H) or tails (T);
For every correct guess SB receives +1 point; for every incorrect guess SB receives a points (with a < +1, possibly a < 0);
We ask SB to try, as best as she can, to get the maximum amount of points at the end of the experiment;
SB may use any kind of method to make her guess; she may, if she wants, use a randomizing method, even use the same coin as the experimenters use, or throw a die, or she may "just make a guess", or use any non-random method.

So, SB is just making a guess but is incentivized to make correct guesses.
The real underlying question is: Which guesses -- or which method of guessing -- can be seen as "rational"? That is the focus of this problem.
Now, further

We require that in advance, before the experiment properly starts, SB  determines her answer. This should be one of the four strings "HH", "HT", "TH" and "TT". We will interpret the first letter as her answer when she is asked the first time. The second letter will be ignored if she is asked only once, otherwise it will be interpreted as her answer the second time she is asked. However, this would implicitly give SB information, since the string has an ordering, and since it never would make sense to guess "TH". To erase the use of this order information the experimenters will arbitrarily either read the provided answer string from right to left or from left to right. SB will not be told in advance how her string is read.

The drugging regime in the standard problem statement has only one purpose: to ensure that SB does not know whether or not she has already been asked the question. This uncertainty can be expressed by SB in the form of a self-locating question: "Is this the first or the second time that I am being asked the question? I may have been drugged, so I'll be darned if I know..." In this problem we want SB to be maximally uncertain about this, in other words, to have no information at all about it. But this maximal uncertainty can also be ensured by my setup, by asking SB to give an answer in advance without being able to use the sequential ordering of that answer. In other words, both the drugging and the fact that some self-locating expression is possible are irrelevant, confounding distractions.
If we set a=-1, and if SB's answer is read from left to right, the payoff matrix becomes
+--------+----+----+
| payoff |  H |  T |
+--------+----+----+
| HH     | +1 | -2 |
| HT     | +1 |  0 |
| TH     | -1 |  0 |
| TT     | -1 | +2 |
+--------+----+----+

Columns correspond to the outcome of the original coin toss; rows to SB's guess. If SB's answer is read from right to left, the matrix essentially remains the same; only the HT and TH rows will swap values.
The asymmetry (+1, -1 vs +2,-2)in the payoff matrix is due to the setup of the experiment where SB is asked twice in case of T and only once in case  of H. Note that if we make the reward for correct answers higher, or if we make the penalty for incorrect answers 0 (or make it much more negative), this will not change the essential analysis below.
Now, there is no clear dominant strategy. Since, if the coin fell H, then HH and either HT or TH will be best, so HH is best; while if the coin fell T, then TT is best. But it's easy to see that always answering TT is the optimal strategy.
If we're allowed to use probabilities and the notion of expectation, then the expected payoff of always choosing TT is (2 - 1)/2 = 0.5; the expected payoff of HH is (1 - 2)/2 = -0.5; the one for HT (and for TH) is 0 (since we don't know if those will be read right to left or left to right). So, if we define a "rational decision" as a decision that maximizes expected payoff, then it's rational to select TT always. (In the standard SB problem this translates to SB guessing T at each awakening.)
If we're not allowed to appeal to probabilistic expectations, can we then still argue that some strategy leads to a better outcome and is thus "rational"? Yes. We can appeal to the minimax/maximin principle.
If the original coin came up H, then the worst outcome is -1, generated by selecting TT or (TH or HT) as answer. If the coin came up T, the worst outcome is -2, generated by selecting HH. We don't know if the coin came up H or T. But if we want (or need) to ignore the probability of the coin coming up H or T, and want to minimize our risks, i.e. want to minimize the maximal possible worst outcome, then again the best (rational) strategy is to always answer TT. (Does it matter in this case, if it's given that the original coin toss was fair? No, if this has any impact, it strengthens the argument. If, on the other hand, it is given that the original toss was biased, then that could undermine the conclusions, since in the extreme case where the coin always comes up H, the worst possible outcome is no longer -2, but -1. In that case, obviously, only guessing HH is rational.)
When we translate these results back into the original, standard problem, we can see that there too, it would be best to always guess T. This immediately implies that the 1/2 solution in the standard problem can not be correct. Since, if the 1/2 solution there is correct, it should not matter if SB guesses TT or guesses HH in my setup. Since this clearly does matter, the 1/2 solution cannot be correct.
The analysis here is essentially the same as Berry Groisman's analysis: The probability that a green ball is retrieved from the box (1/3) does not equal the probability that a green ball was placed in the box (1/2), even though both depend causally on the same original event. As in the Boy-or-Girl paradox, as analysed by Maya Bar-Hillel, when answering a probability brain teaser, it's not just the content of the information that matters, but also how we (who are using that information) came by that information. If we accept Groisman's analysis (or my sketched analysis as above), then it also follows that (1) self-locating beliefs are irrelevant in this problem and that (2) there most definitely is no process of "updating of credences" happening in SBs mind, when she considers the original coin toss and her guesses (or rational credences) during the experiment.

Hi! An interesting approach, but i do not think you can derive any probabilities from a strategy purely based on the payouts (the penultimate paragraph). This is erroneous in the same vein as the betting approach was in the other question.
Also, concerning Groisman, why do you think he never applies his mechanical approach to the actual problem? I believe he would have to end up as a halfer, if he did so (since either the box contains all red or all green balls with prob. 1/2, irrespective of their numbers, for the actual experiment).

If you read Groisman's paper you will see he does apply his approach to the SB problem.

Thanks, but unfortunately i dont see this. Is there a newer, revised version of the paper you linked (from 8 Jun 2008)?
This paper only applies the mechanical approach to a large number of trials. And while this is derived from the original SBP, it stops short of applying it to the actual question. He answers a different question and then just takes that answer instead, claiming it "should be no different". It is - just try his approach, but for a single trial, yourself.
(Also, at least one number from the end of 2.2 is plainly wrong, see: 'avg. number of green balls added per trial = 1/3'.)

@Pepe - If on average 1 green ball is added for every 2 red balls, then the avg nr. of green balls in the urn is 1/3? There is no other paper I'm aware of. Imo the explanation is fine and complete. (The 1/3 conclusion btw is also reached via other arguments by Michael Titelbaum in his book Bayesian Epistemology.)

I agree, the avg. number of green balls in the urn after many trials would be 1/3 of the balls in the urn. But the paper says "the average number of green balls which the device puts in the box on each trial is 1/3", which is clearly false, but is the basis of much of the argument. Compare with "The total average number of balls which the device puts in the box on one trial is [...] 3/2". This would imply 7/6 avg. red balls being put into the box per trial...
But the main point stands regardless: just apply this approach to the actual, single trial SBP and see where it leads you.

Well, no. Denying the premise does not solve the problem. It merely is a motivation to ignore the problem, but it doesn’t provide a solution.

Consider that you try and help a child learn math. You might give them an exercise like this:

Consider that you have five apples and eat three of them. How many apples do you have left?

The child just replies that they don’t eat apples.
Did they solve the problem? In fact, did they even understand the underlying problem, not just the story presented to make it accessible?

Sure, you can ignore problems on technicalities. But it doesn’t mean you solved them.
